# Is it possible to have a day and night map with lights in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

Is it possible to create an OpenLayers map with day and night with lights instead of the shadowed style found on the ol-ext examples? I thought about having 2 layers and adding transparency to the shadowed part to expose the night layer underneath, but I'm not sure how to go about that just yet.

Here's an example of what I'm aiming for:

[image: img_openlayers_map]

Comment: Clip one layer with the geometry (dark or light region) similar to https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-clipping-vector.html